# tracking active allocations can't be selected on Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, instruments

I am trying to change the options to only track active allocations and here's what I see:

[image]

For some reason, I can't seem to change this. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop recording. Configure. Record.